# Not sure why I'm getting "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python, typeerror

I had working code, but it gave me the same `Invest_amount` every year (did not add the previous year's interest), so I created a `Starting_balance` to try and fix this.

However, now it gives me this error message:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str. But I put str in front of the value?
```

My code:

```py
InvestAmount = int(input("Enter the intial investment amount: "))
Years = int(input("Enter the number of years to invest: "))
Rate = float(input("Enter the intrest rate (as %): "))
TotalInterestEarned = 0
for i in range(Years):
     InterestEarned = round(InvestAmount*(Rate/100),2)
     EndingBal = round(InvestAmount+InterestEarned , 2)
     Starting_balance = (InvestAmount + InterestEarned)
     print("Starting Balance: for year " + (i+1)+"$"+str(Starting_balance))    
     print("Ending balance: for year" +(i+1)+"$"+str(EndingBal))
     print("Total interest earned: for year" +(i+1)+"$"+str(InterestEarned))
```

Comment: It is most likely complaining about the `(i + 1)`.

Comment: `(i+1)` is an `int`. Just make it `str(i+1)`. It will convert it to string.

Answer (score 3):

`"abc" + (i+1)` is adding an integer to a string. Consider using an f-string like this:

```
print(f"Starting Balance: for year {i+1} ${Starting_balance}")
```

It's more readable and performs the needed casting for you.

Comment: What does f-string mean?

Comment: @CWoolford f-strings are very useful (available in 3.6 or more), try [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-f-strings-tutorial-how-to-use-f-strings-for-string-formatting/)

Comment: @CWoolford note how the string is pre-fixed with an `f` - that causes it to automatically be formatted, like with `'string {}',format()`, but without all the fluff.

Answer (score 1):

You can only concatenate two strings, you are trying to concatenate int and str

```
InvestAmount = int(input("Enter the intial investment amount: "))
Years = int(input("Enter the number of years to invest: "))
Rate = float(input("Enter the intrest rate (as %): "))



TotalInterestEarned = 0
for i in range(Years):
      InterestEarned = round(InvestAmount*(Rate/100),2)
      EndingBal = round(InvestAmount+InterestEarned , 2)
      Starting_balance = (InvestAmount + InterestEarned)
      
      print("Starting Balance: for year " + str((i+1))+"$"+str(Starting_balance))  # change int to str as well str(i+1)  
      print("Ending balance: for year" +str((i+1))+"$"+str(EndingBal)) # same here 
      print("Total Interest Earned: for year" +str((i+1))+"$"+str(InterestEarned)) # same here
```

Answer (score 1):

Everybody has pretty much gone over the solution but I hopefully can add a little more context for those unfamiliar with types. So when you define i, it is an int. On the other hand, the string you're trying to put it in is "Starting Balance:..." meaning it is a string. With integers `5 + 5 = 10`. Adding integers is standard. Similarly, python is clever enough to understand `"con" + "cat" = "concat"` as essentially you're tacking on the end of a string.

Now what happens when you do `"con" + 5 = ERROR` because python doesn't understand what adding an integer to a string means. Does it mean you should turn `"con"` into an integer representation and add 5 that way or does it mean to tack the number five so it becomes `"con5"`? (Note some language allow this addition and it sometimes can get weird. Python is strongly typed so we don't have to consider that possibility.)

In other words, we have to make that distinction otherwise we're mismatching types. In all the solutions, what's happening is we're turing `i+1` into some string, either by enacting `str()` or f-strings.

Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Python is _dynamically typed_, not strongly typed. Python generally won't implicitly convert between types - which, I think, is the point you were trying to make. Generally = doing `print(5)` works without having to do `print(str(5))` because print will look for the `__str__` or `__repr__` method on objects (inherited, or otherwise) and call that to _print_ things. Good that you noted Python _doesn't do implicit type conversion_ like `"con" + 5` unlike some other languages - but that's not related to strong or dynamic typing. `"con" * 5` does work, to produce `"conconconconcon"`.

Comment: You're absolutely right but I gotta disagree, it is both dynamically typed and strongly typed. It decides types at run time. Strongly typed means you can't mix the types easily.

Comment: Indeed, Python is strongly typed (**I was incorrect to say it wasn't**) but that **_doesn't affect the mix-ability of types_**. That has more to do with [Duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). `x + y` works as long as `x` has `__add__` which supports the type of `y`, or `y` has `__radd__` which supports the type of `x`. And the same expression could be used with different types for each of `x` and `y` (dynamic) but it only works when the two objects meet the criteria above (duck). Which is why `"con" * 5` works but `"con" + 5` doesn't. We're mixing types in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
print(f"Starting Balance: for year {i+1} $ {Starting_balance}") 
# and other code...
```

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to prepend `str` to (i+1) like so:

```
print("Starting Balance: for year " + str((i + 1)) + " $" + str(Starting_balance))
print("Ending balance: for year " + str((i + 1)) + " $" + str(EndingBal))
print("Total Interest Earned: for year " + str((i + 1)) + " $" + str(InterestEarned))
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake another approach would be to use `,` and let the `print` function do its thing.

The print function takes a single object or multiple objects seperated by `,` and will be convert to a string and be printed on the screen.

```
InvestAmount = int(input("Enter the intial investment amount: "))
Years = int(input("Enter the number of years to invest: "))
Rate = float(input("Enter the intrest rate (as %): "))


TotalInterestEarned = 0
for i in range(Years):
    InterestEarned = round(InvestAmount * ( Rate / 100),2)
    EndingBal = round(InvestAmount + InterestEarned , 2)
    Starting_balance = (InvestAmount + InterestEarned)
      
    print("Starting Balance: for year ", (i + 1), "$", Starting_balance)    
    print("Ending balance: for year", (i + 1), "$", EndingBal)
    print("Total Interest Earned: for year", (i + 1), "$", InterestEarned)
```

This is **not** the best approach, The other answers are much better.